# Updating PHP from JavaScript for loop

Tags: javascript, php, for-loop

I currently have a JavaScript for loop which increments 'i'. I want to use this to increment a string within a PHP function call like so:

```
for (var i=1; i <= <?php echo $totalPages[0] ?>; i++){

         if(selection=="page"+i){

            <?php 

            $test = 'page'.+i; 

            ?>

            document.getElementById("commentid").value = "<?php query2($test,$_SESSION['courseID'], $_SESSION['userID']) ?>";


         }

    }
```

This function should call the function query2('page1,2,3,4...',$_SESSION['courseID'], $_SESSION['userID']) incrementing 'pagei'. Although i get the following error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

Comment: Congrats. You have a soup.
this line is so much wrong : $test = 'page'.+i;

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is client-side, PHP is processed on the server side and will not be in the HTML output/the environment the JavaScript will run in. What you are attempting is simply not possible.

Comment: OK thanks I will try and find another way to do this

Answer (score -1):

So you would like sth similar to:

```
var totalPages = <?php echo $totalPages[0] ?>
var comments = [''<?php 
                    for($i=1;i<$totalPages[0];$i++) 
                        echo(",'".query2("page".$i,$_SESSION['courseID'], $_SESSION['userID'])."'"); 
                  ?>]

for (var i=1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
     if(selection=="page"+i){
        document.getElementById("commentid").value = comments[i];
     }
}
```